# JavaFX application dark screen

Tags: java, javafx-2, java-7

I have problems with JavaFX applications on my system. When I run such applications all I see is app window with dark background. I try to run my own applications, Netbeans samples and Scene Builder. Maybe the reason is my OS - it is Windows 7 Starter. JavaFX version 2.2, Oracle JDK version 1.7.09.
Can somebody explain such behavior and suggest how to fix it.

Comment: It could be an issue with your video card drivers. Are you using an ATI Radeon card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try to update your videodrivers.
2. Try to run JavaFX in software mode: `java -Dprism.order=j2d -jar Ensemble.jar`.

If it works then driver or videocard compatibility is an issue. In this case, please, file an issue to http://javafx-jira.kenai.com with your OS, videocard model and driver version.

Comment: But application is working normally in software mode. Thanks! It is much better than nothing.

Comment: I still advise you to file an issue with your details. Thus dev team can fix it or add your card to "blacklist" so software mode would be enabled by default and other people wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Done. I hope it'll help somebody.

Comment: -Dprism.order=sw